# VB.NET NOT RECOGNIZING CHARACTER FROM SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, odbc, teradata

Buen día a todos, estoy intentando descargar información de teradata con una instrucción select, el problema es que cuando lo hago en vb a través de código algunos de los caracteres del resultado en el recordset contienen acentos y no son reconocidos por ejemplo: ú,ü,û . Esto sucede cuando comienzo la lectura del recordset en el cual fueron almacenados.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo obtener estos caracteres? ya que la lectura especifica del campo que lo contiene devuelve un campo vacio imposible de identificar.
Ya intenté cambiar mi string de conexión a ASCII y utf8.

mi código es el siguiente.

```
Public Function Connect_DSN5(ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Connection_String = "Data Source=DSN5; Database=DSN5; Persist Security Info=True; Session Mode=ANSI;"
            Pass = Password
            Connect()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function Fill_Recordset(ByVal Query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
        Recordset1 = New ADODB.Recordset
        With Recordset1
            .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
            .Open(Query, Connection, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockUnspecified)
        End With
        Return Recordset1
    End Function
```

muchas gracias,saludos.

Comment: La base de datos que codificación maneja?

Comment: No estoy seguro, no soy el administrador de la tabla pero podría ser utf8,ASCII o latin, estuve investigando cómo saber la codificación sin embargo para teradata las default son las antes mencionadas.

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde Stack Overflow o accediste directamente a Stack Overflow en español? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y sería útil saber el motivo, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara, explicitando que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.